# trying to understand why git pull worked and git fetch did not

Tags: git

I had forked a directory, cloned my fork, and then files were added to the origin directory that I now wanted on my computer.

To sync a forked directory, I read that I was supposed to do git fetch upstream. But this didn't work in my case. I ended up having to do git remote add XXX and then git pull XXX.

Can someone explain what the difference is between git pull and fetch?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the differences between 'git pull' and 'git fetch'?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/292357/what-are-the-differences-between-git-pull-and-git-fetch)

Answer (score 2):

When you fork a project, and clone your fork, the `upstream` remote is not created automatically.  You have to create the `upstream` remote, using the `git remote add` command, then you should be able to use either `git fetch upstream && git merge upstream/master`, or `git pull upstream master`.

I think if you try your fetch again, it will work, now that you have your `upstream` remote.

https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo/

Answer (score 0):

When you clone a repository with `git clone`, the remote that you get is called `origin`, not `upstream`. `git fetch origin` or just `git fetch` should have done the trick.